# Indent all children

Tags: html, css

I am uncertain why this doesn't work how I expect it to:

**HTML**

```
<details>
  <summary>SomeObject</summary>
  <details>
    <summary>SomeObject</summary>
    <div>someField: 1</div>
    <div>someOther: "abc"</div>
  </details>
  <div>someField: [1,2,3]  </div>
</details>
```

**CSS**

```
details > * {
  margin-left: 10em;
}
```

What I expected was:

```
> SomeObject
  > SomeObject
    someField: 1
    someOther: "abc"
  someField: [1,2,3]
```

However what I get is:

```
> SomeObject
  > SomeObject
  someField: 1
  someOther: "abc"
someField: [1,2,3]
```

I don't understand because `details > *` is meant to select all children of details right? So I should be indenting all children of details, which includes `<div> someField: [1,2,3]</div>`... However, in this case, this is not effected for some reason... And I can't explain why. Any ideas?

```css
details > * {
  margin-left: 10em;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>SomeObject</summary>
  <details>
    <summary>SomeObject</summary>
    <div>someField: 1</div>
    <div>someOther: "abc"</div>
  </details>
  <div>someField: [1,2,3]  </div>
</details>
```

Comment: are you looking something like this https://jsfiddle.net/prfeuk16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My friend came up with this:

```css
details > *:not(summary){
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>SomeObject</summary>
  <details>
    <summary>SomeObject</summary>
    <details>
      <summary>SomeObject</summary>
      <div>someField: 1</div>
      <div>someOther: "abc"</div>
    </details>
    <div>someField: 1</div>
    <div>someOther: "abc"</div>
  </details>
  <div>someField: [1,2,3]  </div>
</details>
```

I like it mainly because I don't have to list all the potential tags of the children of the details tag.

Answer (score 0):

The `margin` is relative to the parent. A `div` within the second `details` element will inherit its parent's `margin`, and have an additional `margin` applied to it.

Consider this example:

```css
details>* {
  margin-left: 10em;
  background: yellow;
}

details {
  background: pink;
}

details details {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>margin-left</summary>
  <details>
    <summary>margin-left + margin-left</summary>
    <div>margin-left + margin-left</div>
    <div>margin-left + margin-left</div>
  </details>
  <div>margin-left</div>
</details>
```

You need to apply an additional left margin so that the last `div` aligns as you want. A nice way to target that `div` is the `only-of-type` selector.

example

```css
details>* {
  margin-left: 10em;
}

details div:only-of-type {
  margin-left: 20em;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>margin-left</summary>
  <details>
    <summary>margin-left + margin-left</summary>
    <div>margin-left + margin-left</div>
    <div>margin-left + margin-left</div>
  </details>
  <div>margin-left 20em</div>
</details>
```

**updated as per comment**

```css
details>* {
  margin-left: 10em;
}

details> :first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>SomeObject</summary>
  <details>
    <summary>SomeObject</summary>
    <div>someField: 1</div>
    <div>someOther: "abc"</div>
  </details>
  <div>someField: [1,2,3]  </div>
</details>
```

Comment: My problem is that you'd have to list every other tag type you also want to indent... Which could be a potentially infinite list... right?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand... I've updated my answer. Basically apply the margin to all elements, but remove it from the first-child - is this helpful?

Comment: A friend of mine figured it wasn't the first child, but the summary tag which was causing the issue. I posted their answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47848326/6302131

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```css
details>*{
  margin-left: 2em;
}
details div{
  margin-left: 4em;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>SomeObject</summary>
  <div>someField: [1,2,3] </div>
  <details>
    <summary>SomeObject</summary>
    <div>someField: 1</div>
    <div>someOther: "abc"</div>
    <details>
    <summary>SomeObject</summary>
    <div>someField: 1</div>
    <div>someOther: "abc"</div>
  </details>
  </details>
</details>
```

Comment: ew... But then you have to list every element you want to indent... which is a potentially infinite list...?

Comment: But now you have the same problem as I had in the original post. someField is no longer indented such that it aligns with `SomeObject`

Comment: Updated @Sancarn

Comment: A friend sent this to me https://stackoverflow.com/a/47848620/6302131 which solves my initial concern.